# Apostrophe Unichar Comparison Problems

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sdk, nsstring, unichar

I am currently looking at parts of a string like this ;

```
            if (thisChar == 'a')
            [self a];

        else if (thisChar == 'b')
            [self b];

        else if (thisChar == 'c')
            [self c];
```

.........

```
        else if (thisChar == '0')
        [self zero];

    else if (thisChar == '1')
        [self one];

    else if (thisChar == '2')
        [self two];

    else if (thisChar == '3')
        [self three];
```

.........

```
            else if (thisChar == '.')
        [self period];

    else if (thisChar == ',')
        [self comma];

    else if (thisChar == '?')
        [self qmark];
```

The problem arises though when I come to

```
else if (thisChar == ''')
        [self three];
```

What I want is the ' (apostrophe) sign but it won't let me do it. I know the reason why, but I don't know a way round it. Would doing this help?

```
NSString *apostropheString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"'"];

unichar apostrophe = [apostropheString characterAtIndex:0];
```

Could I use an isEqualToString?

```
if ([apostrophe isEqualToString: thisChar])
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

---

I have found a way around it by doing the following;

1). Create an NNString with a single character which is an apostrophe

```
NSString *apostropheString = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"'"];
```

2). Get it to convert it to a unichar called "app", as it is zero-indexed and there is only         one character the index is 0.

```
unichar app = [apostropheString characterAtIndex:0];
```

3). I then say if "thisChar" is equal to "app" run "qmark"

```
else if (thisChar == app)
        [self qmark];
```

I hope this helps for anyone with the same problem!

Comment: Don't worry I have found a way around this! View edit for information.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must escape the apostrophe with a backslash: `'\''` .

Comment: It works! Thanks, I suppose it is better than my way as it is shorter.